# Saving eloquent objects dynamically after looping

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save a property based on an array that contains IDs. If the array contains the ID, then the property is 1. It is 0 otherwise:

```
public function save_item(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->authorize() == false) {
        return back()
            ->withErrors($request)
            ->withInput();
    }

    $my_items= Item::where("owner_id", Auth::user()->owner_id)->get();

    foreach ($my_items as $my_item) {
        if (isset($request->property)) {
            foreach ($request->property as $property) {
                if ($property== $my_item->id) {
                    $my_item->property= 1;

                } else {
                    $my_item->property= 0;

                }
            }
        } else {
            $my_item->property= 0;
        }



        if (isset($request->otherproperty)) {
            foreach ($request->otherpropertyas $otherproperty) {
                if ($otherproperty == $my_item->id) {
                    $my_item->otherproperty= 1;

                } else {
                    $my_item->otherproperty= 0;

                }
            }
        } else {
            $my_item->otherproperty= 0;

        }

        if (isset($request->delete)) {
            foreach ($request->delete as $delete) {
                if ($delete== $my_item->id) {
                    $my_item->destroy($my_item->id);
                }
            }
        }
       my_item->save();
    }

    return back();
}
```

I expect this function to loop through all IDs and save the property as 1 if the ID matches, or 0 otherwise.

Instead. This function saves **only the last ID**.

The delete loop works, though.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
Item::where("owner_id", Auth::user()->owner_id)->get();
```

Will return an Eloquent collection. In that case, you can use `pluck`and `contains` to avoid this loop.

Example:

```
$my_item->property = $my_items->pluck('property')->contains($request->property);
```

For more information about pluck and contains methods:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-contains